# Android Hotspot with MAC filtering.

Tags: android

I am using a Wifi Hotspot where I like to filter certain devices from my Hotspot. The best way is through MAC filtering. I used the code to drop the device from Kernel using

```
try {
                String mac=macfilter.getText().toString();
                proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport PORT -m mac ! --mac-source "+mac+" -j DROP");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

where mac is the string I used to store the MAC address of the device that I want to remove from my hotspot. But the code not giving the response . Can anyone help me to find the right solution

Comment: Is there reason to believe iptables is installed on the device, and that the configuration tool will work for an application userid (vs only for the superuser) ?   Also it may be worth running some tests on a desktop linux (or linux-based router?) or with the adb shell to verify that the command you are issuing is one which will have the intended effect.